# How to get specific inheritant entity using generic dao and service layer

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, orm

Working on my spring mvc project I face following issu:
I have UnitAppUser, VStanAppUser and RjuAppUser entity classes which extend User entity. User entity stores some general informations. Rest of inheritant entities stores the references to the particular entities (UnitAppUser has a field Unit type, VStanAppUser has a VStan type so on). 
Here is my parent User entity

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name="app_user")
    public class User implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6628717324563396999L;

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name="SSO_ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
private String ssoId;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name="PASSWORD", nullable=false)
private String password;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name="FIRST_NAME", nullable=false)
private String firstName;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name="LAST_NAME", nullable=false)
private String lastName;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name="EMAIL", nullable=false)
private String email;
}
```

Here's my child classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "unit_app_user")
public class UnitAppUser extends User implements Serializable {

@JoinColumn(name = "UNITWORK", referencedColumnName = "ID")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private UnitDepart unitdepart;

public UnitDepart getWorkat() {
    return unitdepart;
}

public void setWorkat(UnitDepart unitdepart) {
    this.unitdepart = unitdepart;
}
}
@Entity
@Table(name="rju_app_user")
public class RjuAppUser extends User implements Serializable{

@JoinColumn(name = "workrju", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Rju rju;
public Rju getWorkat() {
    return rju;
}
public void setWorkat(Rju rju) {
    this.rju = rju;
}
}
```

and finally my VStan entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="vstan_app_user")
public class VstanAppUser extends User implements Serializable{

@JoinColumn(name = "WORKSTATION", referencedColumnName = "kod")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Vstan vstan;

public Vstan getWorkat() {
    return vstan;
}

public void setWorkat(Vstan vstan) {
    this.vstan = vstan;
} 
}
```

How to write generic dao and service to get specific entity? 
As a result I should have something like this

```
userService.findBySSOId("somessoId").getWorkat() //should return UnitDepart, Rju or VStan
```

Comment: Did you utilize inheritance in your database? Hibernate could do the rest then.

Comment: Using a Discriminator in your User entity should do the trick. You would still need to cast the object returned by your UserService to the correct type before calling getWorkAt() however.
I don't know of any way around that due to Java's static typing.

Comment: I can get Class by the way: userService.findBySSOId("somessoId").getClass() gives to me the Class I want. But I'd like Object

Comment: Since you want to have all the users implement a method `getWorkat()` returning all the different types `Vstan, UnitDepart, Rju`, it would seem `Vstan, UnitDepart, Rju` should form an inheritance hierarchy, not `User`s. You would then need only one `User` class with a many-to-one  association to a base class `Department` (or `Company`, or whatever `Vstan, UnitDepart, Rju` are)

Comment: Also, are `Vstan, UnitDepart, Rju` indeed different? It seems you would like to use them interchangeably. Maybe what you modelled as separate classes should really be distilled in a `DepartmentName` enum field within `Department`?

Comment: yes, Vstan, UnitDepart, Rju are different entities. You want me to create Vstan, UnitDepart and Rju entities which extend a Department entity?

Comment: You know system has users which could work at only one of them Vstan, UnitDepart, Rju

Comment: here is the code https://github.com/shone1991/sprintalonsystem

Comment: Should Department class be abstract class? if yes, then how I can organise @id, because type of Vstan's id is String and can not be changed. I mean UnitDepart has Integer type of Id, Rju has Integer type of Id. If I'm not wrong Id can not simultaneously be in different type. Isn't it? Sorry my broken english by the way